# Solr Index using Avro files

Tags: solr, avro, inverted-index

I have build large inverted index and I have stored my inverted index in avro format not I want to expose this as a service. I was wondering is there a way to load avro files to solr so solr can index the inverted index that I have built.

Here is how my inverted-index looks like:

```
{"key":"10.08","bucket":0,"itemIds":[161049555960]}
{"key":"100-1000-pcs","bucket":0,"itemIds":[590143038066]}
{"key":"11-2972","bucket":0,"itemIds":[130941586664]}
{"key":"1106200","bucket":0,"itemIds":[111132254095]}
{"key":"1370","bucket":0,"itemIds":[380680582645]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use Apache Flume to process the Avro source, and use the Solr Sink to index them. (Tho I'm not very familiar with Flume.)

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/morphlines-the-easy-way-to-build-and-integrate-etl-apps-for-apache-hadoop/